# TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined - React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to call my rest api. but I got this error:

[image]

restApi.js:

```
import {customerbyidGetAction} from '../../redux/actions/restActions'


export default function customerbyidGet(dispatch) {
    
    return () => {
      dispatch(customerbyidGetAction());
        fetch('https://***.com/api/v1/home',{
            method:'GET',
            headers:{
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'token':1234
            }//,
           // body: JSON.stringify({'customerId': 1})
        })
        .then(res => {
            const r = res.json();
            return r;
        })
        .then(res => {
            if(res.error) {
                throw(res.error);
            }
            console.log('then rest')
          dispatch(customerbyidGetAction());
            return res;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('r456r'+error);
           dispatch(customerbyidGetAction());
        })
    }
}
```

Panel.js

```
import customerbyidGet from '../../../api/rest/restApi';

class Panelclass extends React.Component {


  componentDidMount(){
    const {customerbyidGet} = this.props;
    customerbyidGet()

  }
  

  render() {


    return (
      <div>
        hi

      </div>
    );
  }
}

Panelclass.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  customerbyidGet: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ data: {} });


  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({
    customerbyidGet: customerbyidGet(dispatch)
}, dispatch)

const Panel = connect(
 mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Panelclass);

export default withStyles(styles)(Panel);
```

restActions.js

```
import * as types from '../constants/restConstants';

export const customerbyidGetAction = (data = { "default value": "some value" }) => ({ type: types.customerbyidGetAction, payload:data });
```

restReducer.js

```
import * as types from '../constants/restConstants';

const initialState = {};
const initialImmutableState = fromJS(initialState);
export default function restReducer(state = initialImmutableState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case types.customerbyidGetAction:
            return {
                ...state,
                data: action.payload
            }

        default:
            // the dispatched action is not in this reducer, return the state unchanged
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Error is popping out from `middlware.js line: 28` Can you share some snippet from that too.

Comment: The stack trace shows that it is from the redux-saga middleware but I'm not seeing any saga code here.